# Approximate unit for an ideal and its limit

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $I$ is a closed ideal of $A$. If $(\pi, H)$ is a cyclic representation of $A$, Could we show $$\pi(u_i)\xi \to \xi $$ where $\{u_i\}$ is an approximate unit for $I$ and $\xi$ is cyclic vector in $H$?

Comment: It does not seem to be true. Take $A$ to be a sum of two unital algebras $A=A_1\oplus A_2,\ I=0\oplus A_2$. Then $u_i=0\oplus 1_{A_2}$ is an approximate unit in $I$. Since $\pi(u_i)$ is a non-trivial projection you must have $\pi(u_i)\xi=\xi$, but then $\xi$ cannot be cyclic for $A$.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: thanks. you are right.